# cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'int*&' to an rvalue of type 'int*'

Tags: c++, arrays, rvalue, lvalue

I am aware that there are some questions similar to this one but I am a beginner in c++ and those examples were a bit difficult to comprehend for me. In my problem, I have a function called `void selectNegatives(int*&,int&,int*&,int&)`. What this function does is it iterates over an input array, removes negative ints from the input and place them in the output arr. For example an expected output is

```
input -> -45 11 6 38 -12 0
output -> null
//execute func
input -> 11 6 38 0
output -> -45 -12
```

My current implementation is as follows. I have removed details of the function because I know the issue is not there.

```
void selectNegatives(
    int*& inputArr, int& inputSize,
    int*& outputArr, int& outputSize
) {
  //details removed but I can add them if requested
}
```

My issue is passing `int arr[] = {-45, 11, 6, 38, -12, 0};` from caller gives me `cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'int*&' to an rvalue of type 'int*'` while passing `int* arr = new int[]{-45, 11, 6, 38, -12, 0};` works. My current understanding is confusing me because isn't arr[] an lvalue?

Comment: please post the code and the complete error message. [mcve]

Comment: Please read [ask] with a [mcve].

Comment: fwiw, " //details removed but I can add them if requested" no, details of the function implementation do not matter when the error is on calling the function. The code that calls the function matters.

Comment: For `int arr[] = ..;` `arr` is an `lvalue` of type `int [6]`. It can bind to a `int *` by decaying, but not to an `int*&`. By decaying it changes to an `rvalue`. What do you expect to happen when you do `inputArr++;` in the function?

Comment: btw of course it is worth to understand this, but once you did you can turn to use `std::vector` and `std::array` for arrays to avoid such headace

Comment: When you pass the array `arr`, it is implicitly converted to `&arr[0]`. Arrays are not pointers, and pointers are not arrays.

Comment: *...I am a beginner in c++...*  Then you should be using `std::vector`.  C-style arrays and memory allocation (and the subsequent memory management) is advanced C++.

Comment: By using `int*&`, is the intent to show that the `int*` is going to be modified by the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Case 1

Here we consider the case when `int arr[] = {-45, 11, 6, 38, -12, 0};`.

Here when passing `arr` as argument it **decays**(from `int[6]` to `int*`] due **type decay** *but the problem is* that this resulting expression is an **rvalue**(prvalue in particular) and since we can't bind an rvalue to a nonconst lvalue reference we get the mentioned error.

This can also be seen from [value category's documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category):

> A glvalue may be implicitly converted to a **prvalue** with lvalue-to-rvalue, **array-to-pointer**, or function-to-pointer **implicit conversion**.

##### Case 2

Here we consider the case when `int* arr = new int[]{-45, 11, 6, 38, -12, 0};`.

In this case, when passing `arr` as argument the expression `arr` is an lvalue which is allowed to be bound to a nonconst lvalue reference and so this time it works.